# socks proxy prevents remote testng

Tags: java, proxy, testng

I just met a problem about using java socks proxy in the TestNG.

I used the VM arguments for java socks proxy as below:

-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1

-DsocksProxyPort=1080

and then start to run my test case based on the TestNG in eclipse, and problem happened with pop-up window which told me that Couldn't contact Remote TestNG, and with the stack trace as below:

```
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:129)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:503)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.BaseMessageSender.connect(BaseMessageSender.java:58)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.connect(MessageHub.java:32)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:84)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I used this proxy setting in other test case without testng, it just works fine. and if i don't use proxy in the testng test case, it's also fine.

so i think it's just because that testng can't reach remote client through my socks proxy. But question is that why testng need to contact the remote client? is there any function for testng need to get from remote side? is it possible to let testng not contact remote client?

Comment: it's solved already, since eclipse communicate with TestNG by socket, so all communication through socket will pass to proxy even 127.0.0.1/localhost, but in proxy side, it's impossible to connect the localhost's application. the solution is adding "-DsocksNonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1" to exclude localhost from proxy, but please note,  "-DsocksNonProxyHosts" is only supported by JDK8 now.

Comment: Your comment should be the answer!